# Increment and decrement buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am novice in jQuery but trying to learn something very basic. I am just trying to build up auto increment/decrement input fields like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="stile_prenota.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="riga numero">
  <input type="text" name="numero" value="0"  readonly="readonly">
  <button class="bottone piu">+</button>
  <button class="bottone meno">-</button>
 </div>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bottone').on("click", function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   var vecchioVal = $button.parent().find("input").val();
   var nuovoVal = parseFloat(vecchioVal);
   if ($button.text() == "+") {
    nuovoVal += 1;
   } else {
    if (vecchioVal > 0) {
    nuovoVal -=  1;
    } else {
    nuovoVal = 0;
    }
   }
   $button.parent().find("input").val(nuovoVal);  
  });
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why if i put the div inside a form it doesn't work?

EDIT Thank you very much

Comment: because buttons are submit buttons by default and submit the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons are submit type by default. So when you put it inside the form and click on button your form gets submitted. Changing the type will solve your problem like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="stile_prenota.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="riga numero">
      <input type="text" name="numero" value="0" readonly="readonly">
      <button type="button" class="bottone piu">+</button>
      <button type="button" class="bottone meno">-</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.bottone').on("click", function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        var vecchioVal = $button.parent().find("input").val();
        var nuovoVal = parseFloat(vecchioVal);
        if ($button.text() == "+") {
          nuovoVal += 1;
        } else {
          if (vecchioVal > 0) {
            nuovoVal -= 1;
          } else {
            nuovoVal = 0;
          }
        }
        $button.parent().find("input").val(nuovoVal);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The form submites because buttons are `type="submit" by default and submit the form.  So set the type to button so they do not submit

```
<button type="button" ..>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are by default submit here is a working version:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bottone').on("click", function() {
   var $button = $(this);
   var vecchioVal = $button.parent().find("input").val();
   var nuovoVal = parseFloat(vecchioVal);
   if ($button.text() == "+") {
    nuovoVal += 1;
   } else {
    if (vecchioVal > 0) {
    nuovoVal -=  1;
    } else {
    nuovoVal = 0;
    }
   }
   $button.parent().find("input").val(nuovoVal);  
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <form>

 <div class="riga numero">
  <input type="text" name="numero" value="0"  readonly="readonly">
  <button type="button" class="bottone piu">+</button>
  <button type="button"  class="bottone meno">-</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```